# Windows PowerShell Snap-In for IIS fails on 32-bit?

Tags: iis, powershell, tfs-power-tools, web-admin

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that will automate my IIS website deployments. I'm trying to run the scripts on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, under 32-bit in:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Whenever I run a WebAdministration command such as this:

```
Get-Website -Name "MYWebsite"
```

I get an error like this:

```
Get-Website : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {688EEE
E5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Website <<<<  -Name "MyWebsite"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Website], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Micr
   osoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetWebsiteCommand
```

Switching to the 64-bit version of PowerShell.exe resolves this issue but makes it impossible for me to also use the Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools PSSnapin, which is a no-go for me.

Any idea how I can overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was a clear answer that fixed the problem for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6872000/852806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to connect the dots.  "urig" answered his own question in another topic:
[TFS Power Tools 2008 Powershell Snapin won't run in on 64-bit in Windows 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501237)

"Cathy Kong of Microsoft was kind enough to provide me with a workaround for this issue. The full details can be found here in the MSDN TFS PowerTools forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/a116799a-0476-4c42-aa3e-45d8ba23739e/?prof=required

The fix is as follows and worked well for me:

Please save the following content and save it as *.reg file and import to Registry(just double click the *.reg file, click OK double)

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell] "PowerShellVersion"="2.0" "Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation" "Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets." "VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft" "DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets." "Version"="10.0.0.0" "ApplicationBase"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools" "AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" "ModuleName"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll" "CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"

Comment: No, the answer to the other question is not relevant here. One is about the TFS powershell snap-in not working under x64; this is about the IIS module not working under x86 as WOW64. Easily confused, but no.

Answer (score 7):

Running:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

actually loads the **32 bit** version of powershell ;-)

This obviously not what you want. Run the version in system32 to get the 64bit version. Yes, really.

You can verify this like:

```
ps> [intptr]::size
4
```

If it returns 4, it's 32 bit. 64 bit powershell will return 8.

-Oisin

Comment: I think the problem he's running into is that he wants to use the TFS Snapin (32-bit only) in conjunction with the WebAdmin module which *appears* to be 64-bit only.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you might try is to load up a 64-bit PowerShell as Oisin says and then use Start-Job -RunAs32 to execute script that loads the TFS PowerTools snapin and executes the TFS cmdlets as necessary.  Be sure to output an required info from the commands that run in the background job.  Use Wait-Job to wait for it to complete then use Receive-Job to get the data from the 32-bit side back into your main 64-bit PowerShell session e.g.

```
PS> [IntPtr]::Size
8
PS> $job = Start-Job { [intptr]::size } -RunAs32
PS> Wait-Job $job

Id              Name      State      HasMoreData     Location     Command
--              ----      -----      -----------     --------     -------
3               Job3      Completed  True            localhost    [intptr]::size


PS> Receive-Job $job
4
```

Comment: Thanks again for setting me straight Keith. I've edited my question to reflect your correction. I'm still at a loss as to how I can get both the IIS PSProvider and the TFS Power Tools PSSnapin to work together. Any ideas?

Comment: I know of no way to load a 32-bit snapin in the *same* PowerShell session as a 64-bit snapin.  With the exception of using a 32-bit background job as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Opening powershell with the below command solved my issue :

```
%SystemRoot%\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Just invoke the powershell 64 bit version with the above command and pass the script path with arguments to it.

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this in the future, I'd like to add that you should double check how you launch powershell. I was getting the same error, and couldn't figure out why the solutions were all in reference to using the 64 bit version, when I thought I already was.

It turns out that because I was running powershell with a third party 32 bit launcher, powershell was falling back to the 32 bit executable, despite being launched from the system32 folder. Thanks to x0n for the method of confirming the version I was using, as this lead me to my solution.