# TFS Power Tools 2008 Powershell Snapin won't run in on 64-bit in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: tfs, powershell, tfs-power-tools

I've installed TFS Power Tools 2008 along with its PowerShell integration features on my Windows 2008 R2 developer machine.

When I try to run the following command to enable the snapin:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
```

in the 32-bit version of PowerShell.exe, under ***C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe*** it works fine. But when I try to do the same in the 64-bit version here: ***C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe*** I get the following error:

```
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this machine.
At line:1 char:13
+ Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgument
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Any idea how to make it work in the 64-bit version? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cathy Kong of Microsoft was kind enough to provide me with a workaround for this issue. The full details can be found here in the MSDN TFS PowerTools forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/a116799a-0476-4c42-aa3e-45d8ba23739e/?prof=required

The fix is as follows and worked well for me:

> Please save the following content and
>   save it as *.reg file and import to
>   Registry(just double click the *.reg
>   file, click OK double)
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
>   "PowerShellVersion"="2.0"
>   "Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
>   "Description"="This is a PowerShell
>   snap-in that includes the Team
>   Foundation Server cmdlets."
>   "VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
>   "DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This
>   is a PowerShell snap-in that includes
>   the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
>   "Version"="10.0.0.0"
>   "ApplicationBase"="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation
>   Server 2010 Power Tools"
>   "AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   "ModuleName"="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation
>   Server 2010 Power
>   Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
>   "CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"

Comment: I had to escape the slashes as shown in Sergey's answer (e.g. "C:\\", not "C:\").  Otherwise, those values didn't import into the registry.

Answer (score 5):

You got it backwards.  The snapin is a 32-bit snapin.  It works fine under PowerShell (x86) ie 32-bit but doesn't work under PowerShell (x64).  Note: even though the folder is called SysWOW64 it isn't 64-bit.  Under 64-bit Windows the native 64-bit binaries go in $env:SystemRoot\System32.  The 32-bit binaries that run under Windows-on-Windows64 layer (ie they thunk from a 32-bit process and pointers to 64-bit OS calls) go in $env:SystemRoot\SysWOW64.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I'll edit my question and fix it. But might you have something that actually solves my problem? :)

Answer (score 3):

**Registry file for TFS Power Tools 2012:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
"PowerShellVersion"="2.0"
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
"DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"Version"="11.0.0.0"
"ApplicationBase"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools"
"AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
"ModuleName"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
"CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"
```