# How to use TFS Powershell commands from 2013 Power Tools

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have installed TFS Power Tools for 2013. But how do I access the powershell commands.

The doc suggests using

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
```

which gives the error:

> Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this
>   computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS Power Tools 2008 Powershell Snapin won't run in on 64-bit in Windows 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501237/tfs-power-tools-2008-powershell-snapin-wont-run-in-on-64-bit-in-windows-2008-r2)

Answer (score 11):

The "PowerTools Cmdlets" options is not installed by default. Please modifying your installation, checking  the "PowerShell Cmdlets" option of the tools.

[image]