# NSIS Installer runs PS1 script. That script tries to install NuGet, but installs it in x86 Program files?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nsis

I have a NSIS installer that runs a ps1 file to install a bunch of stuff and set up networking configurations.

When it runs the script it installs NuGet into the ProgramFilesx86 and for some reason when i call "Install-Module xNetworking" it cant find it, but if its installed in the ProgramFiles dir it works just fine.

I have the SetRegView 64 option in the nsi file.

Why is NuGet getting installed in the 32-bit directory instead of the 64? Is there an option im missing?

Command to install nuget is just "Install-PackageProvider NuGet -force"

Comment: So I found out that NSIS is a 32 bit process which explains my issue, still cant find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) will redirect 32-bit applications to the 32-bit Program Files directory on 64-bit Windows.

```
!include x64.nsh
RequestExecutionLevel Admin

Section
StrCpy $InstDir $ProgramFiles32
${If} ${RunningX64}
StrCpy $InstDir $ProgramFiles64
${EndIf}
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
SetOutPath $InstDir
File NativeThing.ps1
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
SectionEnd
```

If you are launching powershell from the installer you might have to [make sure you are using 64-bit powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38981021) as well.