# Elastic Beanstalk post install script won't execute correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to publish a .NET core application to Elastic Beanstalk and they will be running on Windows Server. I want to make some changes to IIS settings... more precisely Queue Length of Application Pool.

I have `aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json` file with the following content

```
{
   "manifestVersion": 1,
   "deployments": {
   "aspNetCoreWeb": [
    {
      "name": "my-dotnet-core-app",
      "scripts": {
        "postInstall": {
          "file": "SetupScripts/setupAppPool.ps1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Inside `setupAppPool.ps1` script is the following content:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$defaultAppPool = Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool

#$defaultAppPool.PSPath

Write-Host "Display Queue Length before change: " -NoNewline
(Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\).queueLength

#Value changed here
Set-ItemProperty -Path $defaultAppPool.PSPath -Name queueLength -Value 3000

Write-Host "Display Queue Length after change: " -NoNewline
(Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\).queueLength
```

If it will be a simple scritp like `hostname` it executes with no problem, however this one fails with the following error:

> ```
> 2022-07-12 17:41:25,025 [INFO] Running config InfoTask-TailLogs
> ```

```
AWS.DeploymentCommands.2022.07.12-17.40.30.log:

Starting deployment for my-dotnet-core-app of type AspNetCoreWeb
Parameters:
    appBundle: .
    iisPath: /
    iisWebSite: Default Web Site
Starting restart of my-dotnet-core-app
---------- Executing command "C:\Windows\system32\iisreset.exe /restart" ----------
---------- CWD "" ----------
Attempting stop...
Internet services successfully stopped
Attempting start...
Internet services successfully restarted
---------- Command complete with exit code 0 ----------
Starting ASP.NET Core web deployment my-dotnet-core-app at C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\my-dotnet-core-app with IIS path Default Web Site/
Copying C:\staging\. to C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\my-dotnet-core-app
Removing existing application from IIS
Adding application to IIS
Commit changes to IIS
---------- Executing command "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command  "& { & \"C:\staging\SetupScripts/setupAppPool.ps1\"; exit $LastExitCode }" " ----------
---------- CWD "C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\my-dotnet-core-app" ----------
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the COM class factory for 
component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:2 char:19
+ $defaultAppPool = Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
 
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the COM class factory for 
component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:7 char:2
+ (Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\).queueLength
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
 
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:10 char:24
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path $defaultAppPool.PSPath -Name queueLength -Valu ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemProp 
   ertyCommand
 
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the COM class factory for 
component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:13 char:2
+ (Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\).queueLength
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
 
Display Queue Length before change: Display Queue Length after change: 
---------- Command complete with exit code 0 ----------
Error messages running the command: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command  "& { & \"C:\staging\SetupScripts/setupAppPool.ps1\"; exit $LastExitCode }" 

Get-ItemProperty : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the COM class factory for 
component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:2 char:19
+ $defaultAppPool = Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
 
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the COM class factory for 
component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:7 char:2
+ (Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\).queueLength
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
 
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:10 char:24
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path $defaultAppPool.PSPath -Name queueLength -Valu ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemProp 
   ertyCommand
 
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Retrieving the COM class factory for 
component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not 
registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At C:\staging\SetupScripts\setupAppPool.ps1:13 char:2
+ (Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\).queueLength
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
 
---------- Executing command "C:\Windows\system32\iisreset.exe /start" ----------
---------- CWD "" ----------
Attempting start...
Internet services successfully started
---------- Command complete with exit code 0 ----------

AWSCommandWrapper.log:
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. This is happening because this script gets executed in 32bit. I was able resolve this issue by forcing the script to run in 64bit inside the script. I couldn't find anywhere to configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run the scripts in 64bit. So I appended my script to have the following code at the beginning which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055924/how-to-launch-64-bit-powershell-from-32-bit-cmd-exe) which will relaunch itself to 64-bit if you are running in 32-bit.

```
#############################################################################
#If Powershell is running the 32-bit version on a 64-bit machine, we 
#need to force powershell to run in 64-bit mode .
#############################################################################
if ($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 -eq "AMD64") {
    write-warning "Y'arg Matey, we're off to 64-bit land....."
    if ($myInvocation.Line) {
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile $myInvocation.Line
    }else{
        &"$env:WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file "$($myInvocation.InvocationName)" $args
    }
exit $lastexitcode
}


write-host "Main script body"

#############################################################################
#End
#############################################################################
```