# COM error "class not registered" from WebAdministration module

Tags: powershell, com, web-administration

I have been given some PowerShell scripts (created by someone else, long ago) to "fix".
I am trying to rebuild them top work with our current sysytem.
The problem is I can't even get past the second line of code.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$webapps = Get-WebApplication
```

This part keeps returning the below error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Can someone explain to me how I get this class registered?

Comment: Is OS x32 or x64? Is PowerShell instance x32 or x64?

Comment: i am using x64 for both

Comment: Double check that you are effectively using x64: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501001/windows-powershell-snap-in-for-iis-fails-on-32-bit